# Finding the threshold at which the second player should re-roll (expected value game)

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

Player 1 rolls a 10 sided fair die. Player 2 rolls a 20 sided fair die. Player 2 is allowed to reroll a second time, but is not allowed to look at player 1's roll before deciding whether they want to reroll or not. If player 2 rerolls, they forfeit the number on their first toss and the game is decided based on player 2's second toss and player 1's toss. Player 1 wins if player 1's toss is greater than player 2's. Player 2 wins if player 2's toss is greater *or equal* to player 1's toss. The loser pays the value of the other player's toss. At what threshold should player 2 decide to reroll or not?

I think the idea is to minimize the expected value of player 1. I think minimizing the probability of player 1 winning wouldn't give us an equivalent answer. So I'm going to proceed based on what we're going to minimize the expected value of player 1. Apparently the threshhold is $7$ and there's some fairly "straightforward" way to arrive at this answer, but I don't see what that could be without writing out a bunch of conditional expectations.

Define $A, B$ to be the result of player 1 and 2's toss, respectively. Denote $N$ to be player 1's profit.

We have

$$
E[N] = E[N | A > B]P(A > B) + E[N | A \leq B] P(A \leq B)
$$

The first term is positive, and the second term is negative. I don't see an easier way to approach this problem besides further conditioning each of those conditional expectations on whether $B$ rerolls or not.
Let $B_1$ denote the result of $B$'s *first* toss.
$B$ will reroll if $B_1 < b$ and not reroll otherwise, so we have:

$$
E[N | A > B]P(A > B) = E[N | A > B, B_1 < b]P(B_1 < b | A > B) + E[N | A > B, B_1 \geq b]P(B_1 \geq b | A > B) \\
E[N | A \leq B]P(A \leq B) = E[N | A \leq B, B_1 < b]P(B_1 < b | A \leq B) + E[N | A \leq B, B_1 \geq b]P(B_1 \geq b | A \leq B)
$$

So, we need to solve

$$
\arg\min_b E[N] = E[N | A > B, B_1 < b]P(B_1 < b | A > B) + E[N | A > B, B_1 \geq b]P(B_1 \geq b | A > B)
+ 
E[N | A \leq B, B_1 < b]P(B_1 < b | A \leq B) + E[N | A \leq B, B_1 \geq b]P(B_1 \geq b | A \leq B)
$$

Is this the right approach? Is there an easier approach to this problem?

---

Here's what I obtained for the conditional expectations (sorry kind of scratch work so far):

We have 4 conditional expectations to solve.
Let's look at $E[N | A > B, B_1 < b]$ first.
Here, player 2 will reroll.
In this case, how many situations are there such that $A > B$?
Well, there are $1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + 9 = 45$ situations.
For this expectation, we don't need to worry about what the threshold $b$ is.

\begin{align}
    E[N | A > B, B_1 < b] = \frac{1}{45}\sum_{i=2}^10 i * (i - 1) = 330/45 = 7\frac{1}{3} 
\end{align}

For the 3rd conditional expectation, we need to consider the situations where we reroll and we have $A \leq B$.
There are $20 + 19 + 18 + \ldots + 11 = 155$.

\begin{align}
    E[N | A \leq B, B_1 < b] = -\frac{1}{155}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10} i * i \right) + \sum_{i=11}^{20} 10i \right] \\
    = -12.4838
\end{align}

Now the second and fourth conditional expectations require us to consider the threshhold.
We know the threshhold is not going to be above for sure.
Let's consider the second conditional expectation first.
Consider $A > B, B_1 \geq b$.
There are $20 - b + 1$ possibilities for $B_1$, i.e., $b, b+1, b+2, \ldots, 20$.
However, to have $A > B$, we must only have $B_1 \leq 10$.
So the number of events with $A > B, B_1 \leq b$ should be $10 - b, 10 - b - 1, \ldots, 1, 0 = \frac{(10-b)(10-b+1)}{2}$

\begin{align}
    E[N | A > B, B_1 \geq b] 
    = \frac{2}{(10 - b)(10 - b + 1)} \sum_{i=b + 1}^{10} i * (i - b) 
\end{align}

Now for the fourth expectation conditional expectation, we need to consider
$A \leq B, B_1 \geq b$.
There are $b + b+1 + b+2 + \ldots + 10 + 10 * 10 = 100 + \frac{10*11}{2} - \frac{b(b-1)}{2} = 155 - 0.5b^2 + 0.5b$ such events.
So we have

\begin{align}
    E[N | A \leq B, B_1 \geq b] = - \frac{1}{155 - 0.5b^2 + 0.5b} \left[ \left(\sum_{i=b}^{10} i^2 \right)  + \sum_{i=11}^{20} 10i \right]
\end{align}

---

Now we have to compute the conditional probabilities.
\begin{align}
    P(B_1 < b | A > B) = \frac{P(A > B | B_1 < b)P(B_1 < b)}{P(A > B)} \\
    = \frac{\frac{45}{200}\frac{b - 1}{20}}{\frac{45}{200}\frac{b - 1}{20} + \frac{(10-b)(10-b+1)/2}{(20-b+1)(10)}\frac{20 - b + 1}{20}}
\end{align}

Now we can get the second conditional probability by taking the complement

\begin{align}
    P(B_1 \geq b | A > B) = 1 - \frac{\frac{45}{200}\frac{b - 1}{20}}{\frac{45}{200}\frac{b - 1}{20} + \frac{(10-b)(10-b+1)/2}{(20-b+1)(10)}\frac{20 - b + 1}{20}}
\end{align}

Now for the third conditional probability

\begin{align}
    P(B_1 < b | A \leq B) = \frac{P(A \leq B | B_1 < b)P(B_1 < b)}{P(A \leq B)} \\
    = \frac{ \frac{155}{200} \frac{b - 1}{20}}{ \frac{155}{200} \frac{b - 1}{20} + \left(1 - \frac{(10-b)(10-b+1)/2}{(20-b+1)(10)} \right) \frac{20-b+1}{20}  }
\end{align}

And the fourth

\begin{align}
    P(B_1 \geq b | A \leq B) =  1 - \frac{ \frac{155}{200} \frac{b - 1}{20}}{ \frac{155}{200} \frac{b - 1}{20} + \left(1 - \frac{(10-b)(10-b+1)/2}{(20-b+1)(10)} \right) \frac{20-b+1}{20}  }
\end{align}

---

Conclusion: I use monte carlo and obtained $b = 10$ as a threshhold, so if $B$ rolls less than $10$ then they should reroll. Obviously $b$ can't be more than 10.

Comment: One way to do it is to work out player $2's$ expected payout for each possible first roll.  That's not terribly difficult.  Natural guesses for the answer would be:  "Roll again if you are below player $1's$ expected roll" or "Roll again if you are below your expected roll."  But it seems possible that the optimal point lies between these two.

Comment: @lulu Indeed the answer is in between. Those are good heuristic bounds though, especially once you see that player 2 expects to win (even without switching).

Comment: @lulu I think enumerating player 2's outcomes from 1 to 9 (we don't need to consider 10-20 since those definitely don't need to be threshold) is easier than the massive amount of work that I just did in the OP

Comment: @anonuser01  Oh, yes.  The work involved isn't bad.  And It's an interesting result.  I don't think it is intuitve that you should rerolll a $9$ but not a $10$....I think you pretty much have to go through each case.

Comment: @lulu Interestingly, I got that the threshold for maximizing player 2's *probability* of winning is actually 7 (player 2 should reroll if they rolled $\leq 7$). Assuming I did that correctly, that's a pretty big difference? I think maximizing player 2's probability of winning is equivalent to maximizing the expected profit, except instead of being paid the amount that you rolled, you just get paid $1$ or lose $-1$.

Comment: @anonuser01  I see the expected payout for $2$ (if there were no option) is $8.025$   which would make holding on $8$ a bad move.  if player $2$ has an $8$, their expected payout is only $4.5$ so rolling again is a good idea.

Comment: @anonuser01  Continuing, I see the expected payout on a $9$ to be $7.1$ which also makes it a good idea to rerolll the $9$, though that one would make me nervous, as there is real risk involved in giving that one up.  At $10$ of course the payout is a guaranteed $10$ so you should stand.

Comment: 2's probability to win something on an arbitrary roll is $\frac{31}{40}$. So it is slightly more likely that you lose if you reroll an 8 or a 9 compared to staying, but the possible winnings are better, and the possible *losses* if you *do* lose in these cases are essentially as high as they can possibly be. Still it would be upsetting to be 2, roll a 9, 1 rolled a 9, and then you reroll and go below a 9--that's a swing from \$9 gain to \$9 loss.

Comment: @lulu My previous comment was about maximizing 2's probability of winning and not maximizing their expected profit. For maximizing their expected profit I got that they should reroll on 9 or less, but for maximizing their probability it's only reroll on 7 or less.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, that sounds plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposed to discuss your work, before presenting my answer.  Unfortunately, while I can solve the problem, my formal knowledge of Probability is inadequate to examine your work.

On the re-roll, Player 2's expectation is as follows:

$(1/2)$ the time, he will roll $> 10.$  If he does so, his average gain is $(15.5)$.

$(1/20)$ of the time, his roll will exactly match player 1.  When this happens, player 2's average gain will be $(5.5).$

The other $(9/20)$ of the time, both he and player 1 will roll $10$ or less, and their rolls won't match.  This case may be ignored, since by symmetry, it must be a break even situation.

Therefore, player 2's expectation is 
$[(1/2) \times (15.5)] + [(1/20) \times (5.5)] = \frac{160.5}{20}.$

---

If player 2 rolls a $9$, and does not re-roll, his expectation is 
$[(.9) \times 9] - [(1/10) \times (10)] = 7.1$

If player 2 rolls a $10$, and does not re-roll, his expectation is 
$[(1.0) \times 10] = 10$

---

Player 2 should re-roll on 9 or less.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to comment/question.

Player 1's expectation, assuming that player 2 re-rolls on 9 or less is simply $(-1) \times $ player 2's expectation.

Player 2's expectation is :

- $(0.45) \times \frac{160.5}{20}.$ 
  This represents player 2 re-rolling on a $9$ or less.
- $(0.55) \times 15.$ 
  This represents player 2 rolling 10 or higher.

Therefore, player 2's expectation, based on the *reroll on 9 or less* strategy is:

$$\left[(0.45) \times \frac{160.5}{20}\right] + 
\left[(0.55) \times 15\right].$$

Comment: I also obtained the same result using monte carlo. Let me look closely at your work now.

Comment: Do you have the value for player 1's expectation if player 2 rerolls on a 9 or less?

Comment: @anonuser01 Give me a few minutes to work that out.

Comment: @anonuser01 See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: I got the same answer. Your approach is so much simpler than mine. I should've tried enumerating a few outcomes first to see. I think the one thing I was hesitant about is if the expected value of player 2 monotonically increases with the threshold in the 1-10 interval, but I think that could've just been determined rather easily from intuition.

Comment: @anonuser01 thanks for the compliment.

Comment: I applied your approach to the game where instead of maximizing player 2's profit, we maximize player 2's probability of winning. I found that the threshold is $7$ (player 2 should reroll if they reroll $\leq 7$. This gives player 2 a 0.90625 probability of winning. That's a pretty big drop off from the threshold of $9$.

Comment: Did you happen to compute player 2's expected profit, based on the alternative strategy?

Comment: Alternative as in using your strategy? If so, yeah, I just did what you did.

Comment: @anonuser01 No, I meant alternative as in trying to maximize chance of winning, and therefore not re-rolling on an 8 or 9.  I suspect that you will be giving up significant expectation in exchange for a higher chance of winning *something*.

Comment: Ah. I just calculated it, I got $11.63875$ for a htreshold of 7 or less.

Comment: I generated a few more using monte carlo. It looks like if the treshold is between 7-10, it's all pretty close together